# TypeScript variable that holds any instance of generic class

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an abstract TypeScript class that represents a user. There are multiple subclasses to represent different 3rd party services. The class has a generic type of a 3rd party service.

I am trying to create an array that can hold any instance of a User but TypeScript is throwing an error.

```
let users: User[] = [
   new TestUser("test-1"),
   new TestUser("test-2"),
   new TestUser("test-3")
]
```

```
export abstract class User<T extends ApiService> {
    public id: string;
    public username: string;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Generic type 'User<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
```

In Java I could do the following to allow any sub-class of User.

```
User<?>
```

How would I do this in TypeScript?

Comment: `let users: User<any>[]`

Answer (score 0):

As Aleksey said:

```
let users: User<any>[]
```

works perfectly!